# UI hang while collapsing multiple panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, twitter-bootstrap-3

Context: jQuery, Bootstrap Panels & Bootstrap Collapse

I am trying to collapse about 300+ Bootstrap panels, but because of the DOM changes the UI Thread freezes.
This is the current code:

```
$('#CollapseAll').click(function() {
    $('.panel-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

There is a `hidden.bs.collapse` event that gets fired after the animation is completed.

How do I collapse the next element only after the event fires?

Answer (score 0):

> hide.bs.collapse  This event is fired immediately when the hide method
>   has been called. hidden.bs.collapse   This event is fired when a
>   collapse element has been hidden from the user (will wait for CSS
>   transitions to complete).

```
$(firstElement).on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
      $(seconedElement).collapse('hide');
})
```

Comment: What is `#myCollapsible` and `element`?

Comment: firstElement and socenedElement,
i updated the answer

Comment: Ah ok that I get, what I am trying to figure it is how to process 300 elements, how do you sequence 300 elements?

Comment: i need to see the HTML of your code to know the relation between elements

are they siblings?

Comment: i will make simple  jsfiddle example for you to know the logic

Comment: The only way I can think of is to, put all elements in a global array, then collapse the first element, then the collapse event would recursively close each one. I was hoping to avoid the global

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I ended up using (not pretty)

The UI doesn't hang and the panels collapse better

```
var collapseQueue;
$('.panel-collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function(){
    if (collapseQueue) {
        var elem = collapseQueue.first();
        collapseQueue = collapseQueue.slice(1);
        setTimeout(function() {
            elem.collapse('hide'); 
        }, 100);           
    }
});
$('.panel-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function(){
    if (collapseQueue) {
        var elem = collapseQueue.first();
        collapseQueue = collapseQueue.slice(1);
        setTimeout(function() {
            elem.collapse('show');
        }, 100);
    }
});

$('#CollapseAll').click(function() {
    collapseQueue = $('.panel-collapse');
    var elem = collapseQueue.first();
    collapseQueue = collapseQueue.slice(1);
    elem.collapse('hide');
});
$('#ExpandAll').click(function() {
    collapseQueue = $('.panel-collapse');
    var elem = collapseQueue.first();
    collapseQueue = collapseQueue.slice(1);
    elem.collapse('show');
});
```